# Multicolumn in longtable is getting out of range, while the rest of the columns are not

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

I have the following longtable which works fine:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|l|p{8.5cm}|}
\caption{Caption: Lorem ipsum}
\label{use-case_1}\\
\hline
\textbf{Use Case \#1}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
\textbf{Goal in Context}       & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum.} \\ \hline
\textbf{Scope \& Level}        & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum.} \\ \hline
\textbf{Requirements Met}      & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline
\textbf{Preconditions}         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\ \hline
\textbf{Success End Condition} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\ \hline
\textbf{Failed End Condition}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\ \hline
\textbf{Primary Actor}         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\ \hline
\textbf{Description}           & \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Action} \\ \hline
                               & 1             & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\ \hline
                               & 2             & TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et augue finibus massa imperdiet interdum id at massa. \\ \hline
\textbf{Extensions}            & \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Branching Action} \\ \hline
                               &             & TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\ \hline
                               &               & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et augue finibus massa imperdiet interdum id at massa. \\ \hline
\textbf{Sub-Variations}        & \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Branching Action} \\ \hline
                               & N/A           & N/A \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: The table generated by the code above]

But if the text in one of the first eight rows (with the multicolumn) is too long, instead of soft-wrapping it like the rest of the columns at the end of the table, it is getting out of range, as shown below:

[image: The table is getting out or bounds]

What can I do so that I can fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using  `l` not `p` in `\multicolumn{2}{l|}` so it is a single line entry with no linebreaking. (not really related to `longtable` you would see the same in `tabular` with no packages at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

As pointed out @DavidCarlisle in his comment, you should use `p{...}` column specifier instead of `l`, as follows:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\bfseries}l|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{9mm}|p{8cm}|}
\caption{Caption: Lorem ipsum}
\label{use-case_1}\\
    \hline
Use Case \#1    & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr8.9cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline
%
Goal in Context & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr8.9cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum.} \\ \hline
Scope \& Level         & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr8.9cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum.} \\ \hline
Requirements Met       & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr8.9cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline
Preconditions          & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr8.9cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{\lipsum[66]} \\ \hline
Success End Condition  & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr8.9cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\ \hline
Failed End Condition   & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr8.9cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\ \hline
Primary Actor          & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr8.9cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\ \hline
Description            & \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Action} \\ \hline
                               & 1             & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\ \hline
                               & 2             & TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et augue finibus massa imperdiet interdum id at massa. \\ \hline
Extensions             & \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Branching Action} \\ \hline
                               &             & TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\ \hline
                               &               & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et augue finibus massa imperdiet interdum id at massa. \\ \hline
Sub-Variations         & \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Branching Action} \\ \hline
                               & N/A           & N/A \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Edit: reuced are widths of the lat two column. Now table is not to wide.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't resolve the problem, it is different from the attached screenshot

Comment: @ZachariasM there was a bad edit later use `p{1cm}` for the middle column (see the updated code) it's still 14pt too wide you need to reduce the width of the last column a bit more